# Is the air velocity and air temperature a vector field?

Tags: vector-fields

The air temperature and the velocity of the air have different  values at different places in the earth's atmosphere. Is the air velocity a vector field? Why or why not? Is the air temperature a vector field? Again, why or why not?

Answer (score 4):

The velocity is a vector field, because velocity is a vector (has a magnitude and a direction), and there is a velocity associated with each point in the atmosphere.

The temperature is not a vector field, because temperature does not have a direction. It only has a magnitude (absolute temperature). The temperature is a **scalar field**, which has a magnitude at each point in the atmosphere.

In general, a field is something that can be different at different points. A vector field has both magnitude and direction at each point. A scalar field has only a magnitude at each point, but it may still vary from one point to the next.

Comment: I fear that calling a gradient a vector field will tend to confuse the OP.  A gradient is a one-form, not a vector field --- in other words, it takes its values in the cotangent bundle, not the tangent bundle. Given a metric, one can identify cotangent vectors with tangent vectors, but the identification is not natural and depends on the choice of metric.

Comment: @WillO  You are absolutely right. I didn't think about that. I deleted the gradient paragraph. Thank you!